# WooCommerce - group downloads by product

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, digital-downloads

In Woocommerce(*My Account page) I can see now an unordered list with all the downloads available, like:

```
<ul class="digital-downloads">
  <li><a href="#">Product 1 - File</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 1 - Another File</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 2 - File</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 2 - Another File</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 3 - File</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 3 - Another File</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I group the downloads by product?, like:

```
<ul class="digital-downloads">
  <li>
    <span>Product 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">File</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another File</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>Product 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">File</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another File</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>Product 3</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">File</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another File</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The code from my theme/woocommerce/my-account/my-downloads.php:

```
<ul class="digital_downloads">
    <?php foreach ( $downloads as $download ) : ?>
        <li>
            <?php
                do_action( 'woocommerce_available_download_start', $download );

                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_available_download_link', '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['download_url'] ) . '">' . $download['download_name'] . '</a>', $download );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_available_download_end', $download );
            ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, I am answering this question very late but I am posting an answer for this just in case anyone else is looking out for the answer.

Please create a child theme and in that child theme create file /woocommerce/my-account/my-downloads.php. Add following content in that file

```
<?php
/**
 * My Orders
 *
 * Shows recent orders on the account page
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

function wdm_print_download_file_name( $download, $product_meta ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $download['downloads_remaining'] ) )
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_available_download_count', '<span class="count">' . sprintf( _n( '%s download remaining', '%s downloads remaining', $download['downloads_remaining'], 'woocommerce' ), $download['downloads_remaining'] ) . '</span> ', $download );

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_available_download_link', '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['download_url'] ) . '">' . $product_meta[$download['download_id']]['name'] . '</a>', $download ); //Print file name
}

if ( $downloads = WC()->customer->get_downloadable_products() ) :
    ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_downloads_title', __( 'Available downloads', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></h2>

    <ul class="digital-downloads">
        <?php
        $all_product_ids = array();
        $all_download_ids = array();
        $download_ids_used_till_now = array();
        foreach ( $downloads as $download ) :
            ?>

            <?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_available_download_start', $download );

            if ( !in_array( $download['product_id'], $all_product_ids ) ) { //Check if current product id is already there in $all_product_ids array. If it goes in this loop, that means it is new product id
                $product_meta = get_post_meta( $download['product_id'], '_downloadable_files', true ); //All download ids of the product

                $all_product_ids[] = $download['product_id']; //Push Current download's Product id to an array

                $all_download_ids = array_keys( $product_meta ); //Get all download ids of the current product

                echo '<li><span>' . get_the_title( $download['product_id'] ) . '</span><ul>'; //Print product name

                $download_ids_used_till_now[] = $download['download_id']; //add download id to an array

                echo '<li>';
                wdm_print_download_file_name( $download, $product_meta );
                echo '</li>';

                $check_if_this_is_last_element = array_values( array_diff( $all_download_ids, $download_ids_used_till_now ) );

                if ( empty( $check_if_this_is_last_element ) ) { //This is last download id of a product
                    echo '</ul></li>'; //close ul and li tags
                }
            } else { //product id is already in use.
                $check_if_this_is_last_element = array_values( array_diff( $all_download_ids, $download_ids_used_till_now ) );

                if ( isset( $check_if_this_is_last_element[0] ) && $download['download_id'] == $check_if_this_is_last_element[0] ) { //This is last download id of a product
                    echo '<li>';
                    wdm_print_download_file_name( $download, $product_meta );
                    echo '</li>';

                    echo '</ul></li>'; //close ul and li tags

                    unset( $download_ids_used_till_now );
                    unset( $all_download_ids );
                } else { //There are few more download ids
                    $download_ids_used_till_now[] = $download['download_id'];

                    echo '<li>';
                    wdm_print_download_file_name( $download, $product_meta );
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
            do_action( 'woocommerce_available_download_end', $download );
            ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Above code is tested with WooCommerce 2.1.12.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I haven't figured it out by myself even if the question is a bit old, so I will test your answer in the coming days.

Comment: Tested today and it works smoothly, exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to add the featured image of the product too? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

The code above seemed to close out the child list too early. So if I had two downloads under one product it would display as

```
<ul class="digital-downloads">
  <li>
    <span>Product 1</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product 1 File 1</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 1 File 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Instead I just changed the html markup to divs. This might not be semantically as correct but got the job done and was more simple to code.

```
function wdm_print_download_file_name( $download, $product_meta ) {
if ( is_numeric( $download['downloads_remaining'] ) )
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_available_download_count', '<span class="count">' . sprintf( _n( '%s download remaining', '%s downloads remaining', $download['downloads_remaining'], 'woocommerce' ), $download['downloads_remaining'] ) . '</span> ', $download );

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_available_download_link', '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['download_url'] ) . '">' . $product_meta[$download['download_id']]['name'] . '</a>', $download ); //Print file name
}

if ( $downloads = WC()->customer->get_downloadable_products() ) :
?>

<h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_downloads_title', __( 'Available Downloads and Videos', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></h2>

<div class="digital-downloads">
    <?php
    $all_product_ids = array();
    $all_download_ids = array();
    foreach ( $downloads as $download ) :
        ?>

        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_available_download_start', $download );

        if ( !in_array( $download['product_id'], $all_product_ids ) ) { //Check if current product id is already there in $all_product_ids array. If it goes in this loop, that means it is new product id
            $product_meta = get_post_meta( $download['product_id'], '_downloadable_files', true ); //All download ids of the product

            $all_product_ids[] = $download['product_id']; //Push Current download's Product id to an array

            $all_download_ids = array_keys( $product_meta ); //Get all download ids of the current product

            echo '<div class="download-title">' . get_the_title( $download['product_id'] ) . '</div>'; //Print product name

        } else { 
            //product id is already in use.
        }

        echo '<div class="download-product">';
        wdm_print_download_file_name( $download, $product_meta );
        echo '</div>';

        do_action( 'woocommerce_available_download_end', $download );
        ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This was done in WooCommerce 2.5.2

Comment: I don't have the same problem. I always have at least two downloads under one product and they both look like you showed for your second file.

Answer (score 0):

i fix

Change 
 the line

```
            if ( isset( $check_if_this_is_last_element[0] ) && $download['download_id'] == $check_if_this_is_last_element[0] )
```

to

```
            if ( isset( $check_if_this_is_last_element[1] ) && $download['download_id'] == $check_if_this_is_last_element[1] )
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question